# How to have nested promises in Python?

Tags: python, nested

Is there a way to have nested function calls?

I just made this: it looks pretty uncommon though.

```
@when_event1_happens
def function1():
    print "event 1 happened"

    @when_event2_happens
    def function2():
        print "event 2 happened"
```

Comment: Your code is valid Python 2 syntax.  The inner function definition will only be executed when the outer function is called.   Your question is rather unclear though.  What are these decorators supposed to do?  What would you like the code to do?

Comment: yes that should work fine .... as sven says event2 wont register until event1_happens ....

Comment: sorry, this code block doesn't seem to look very common

Comment: I was wondering if this is pythonic

Comment: If you can read it and it works as coded, it's Pythonic

Comment: That's wrong. Pythonistas have strict standard - I'm sure you know that.